# how to delete the entire line if line has specific word in python

Tags: python

i have a .txt file like this:

```
the pen is yellow
pen is yellow
    hi
hello
```

and i want to delete the entire line that include "pen" word

like this:

```
    hi
hello
```

and i tried this

```
with open("myfile.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("myfile.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        if "pen" in line:
            f.write(line)
```

---------------------------AND------------------------------
how i delete just the "pen" word in the .txt file

Comment: Do you want to *delete* the relevant lines or do you want them to be *empty*?  You know you can negate conditions with `not`, like `if not "pen" in line` or even `if "pen" not in line`?

Comment: @fsimonjetz i want them empty

Comment: Out of the scope of your question, but for this action, I think a simple linux command would do instead of a whole Python script. You could do something like: `grep -v pen myfile.txt`

Comment: @Itération122442 i have to use python this is a school project and is have to be python

Comment: @keremketenci22 it's alright. Just put a note in the thing you send back to your teacher saying that, while this is for education, `grep`, if working with a machine that has it, is designed for this very specific purpose ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First** you need to put the result on another file (myfile2) and you need to print on this file the lines thats not contain "pen".

```
with open("myfile.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("myfile2.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        if "pen" not in line:
            f.write(line)
        else:
            f.write("\n")
```

**Second** to just substitute the word use replace(,)

```
with open("myfile3.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        line = line.replace("pp","")
        f.write(line)
```